# File upload after NGRX dispatch action

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm currently using ng2 file upload from valor software to perform image upload to server.

My previous code was written this way: 
After added a new post, the image uploader will upload the image based on the response id (which is the post Id).

```
this.socialPostService.addPost(postHeader).subscribe((response: PostHeader) => {
  this.pictureUploader.setOptions({
    url: this.baseUrl + 'socialphotos/post/' + response.id
  });
  this.pictureUploader.uploadAll();
}, error => {
  // this.errorService.handleError(error);
  this.errorService.handleError(error);
});
```

I'm learning state management and moving this to NGRX approach and i found it difficult to perform the image upload after added the post because i could not return the post id from the post adding action.

Below is the new approach im trying :

Effect to work with server and add the post.

```
@Effect()
    AddPost$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<PostActions.AddToPost>(
            PostActions.ActionTypes.Add_To_Post
        ),
        mergeMap((action: PostActions.AddToPost) =>
            this.socialPostService.addPost(action.payload).pipe(
                map((newPost: PostHeader) =>
                        new PostActions.AddSuccess(newPost)
                ),
                catchError(err => of(new PostActions.AddFailed(err)))
            )
        )
    );
```

Dispatch add post action :

```
this.store.dispatch(new postHeaderActions.AddToPost(postHeader));
//Return post Id and perform image uploading based on that
```

Is there anyway to return the newly added post id from the ngrx effect so that i could perform image uploading based on that?

Thanks

Comment: What values are you getting if you put console.log in  `map` of `addPost`?

Comment: Also you need to listen to `PostActions.AddSuccess` to call file upload. Or you need to use the selector, pick the `postId` and call the file upload.

Comment: @KiraAG Do you mean newPost: PostHeader? This is the newly added post, similar to the response: PostHeader from first approach

Comment: @KiraAG Do you mean like this? 

this.store.dispatch(new postHeaderActions.AddToPost(postHeader));
//Call selector to pickup postId and perform image upload

Comment: Sorry I meant, are you getting values in `map` of `addPost` ?

Comment: yeah like that.(for selector id approach)

Comment: @KiraAG, yes I confirm that there is value returned from the map

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195451/discussion-between-kiraag-and-scholarwithfire).

Answer (score 0):

You should change a little the design to better integrate the spirit of NgRx.

I suggest you to :

- create a shared service `UploadService` which hold a reference to `FileUploader`
- this service will listen to `FileUploader` events, and dispatch actions to inform store (state).
- your view component could use `FileUploader` to manage drop zone for instance (or you should develop this part), but for the rest, it should interact with actions / selectors.
- manage a little workflow, like :

  - dispatch AddNewPostHeader => NewPostHeaderCreated => UploadFiles => FilesUploaded
- manage status flags into state, like `headerAdding`, `fileUploading`... to inform your view component of current process.

Hope my explanation is clear, and will help you.